# How to change .NET WSDL to make it SAP compatible?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, wsdl, sap-basis

I am trying to consume webservices from a .NET environment on SAP.
But when I try to create the logical port in the SAP SOAMANAGER I get the error:

> SRT-Framework-Ausnahme: Initialer Wert "consumer context table" in
>   Methode IF_SRT_WSP_CONFIG_REGISTRY~CREATE_CONTEXTS_FROM_WS der Klasse
>   CL_SRT_WSP_CONFIG_REGISTRY

The WSDL-Analyzer shows **2 unsupported elements**:

```
<http:BasicAuthentication xmlns:http="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
```

and

```
<sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><wsp:Policy xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xml:base="https://external-server.com/Webservice.svc?singlewsdl"><wsp:ExactlyOne><wsp:All><sp:TransportToken><wsp:Policy xml:base="https://external-server.com/Webservice.svc?singlewsdl"><wsp:ExactlyOne><wsp:All><sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/></wsp:All></wsp:ExactlyOne></wsp:Policy></sp:TransportToken><sp:AlgorithmSuite><wsp:Policy xml:base="https://external-server.com/Webservice.svc?singlewsdl"><wsp:ExactlyOne><wsp:All><sp:Basic256/></wsp:All></wsp:ExactlyOne></wsp:Policy></sp:AlgorithmSuite><sp:Layout><wsp:Policy xml:base="https://external-server.com/Webservice.svc?singlewsdl"><wsp:ExactlyOne><wsp:All><sp:Strict/></wsp:All></wsp:ExactlyOne></wsp:Policy></sp:Layout></wsp:All></wsp:ExactlyOne></wsp:Policy></sp:TransportBinding>
```

So I looked at the WSDL files in detail and **removed the content of the wsp:All tag**, which is:

```
            <http:BasicAuthentication xmlns:http="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http"/>
            <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Strict/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>
```

Creating the logical port from the **edited offline WDSL file worked now**! So I guess, the problem is originated in the way, the BasicAuthentication and the TransportBinding tags are designed.

Of course **the original external WDSL file has to be adapted**.

***What do I have to change in the .NET environment, in order to generate a SAP compatible WSDL file? Do I have to adapt the web.config file?***

Comment: Just use `basicHttpBinding` in the service. It is currently using `wsHttpBinding`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Currently I am using basicHttp**s**Binding. This was chosen, because the WebService should only be able to communicate through HTTPS. Can I use another binding, e.g. your suggested basicHttpBinding and communicate over HTTPS, anyway?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I replace `basicHttpsBinding` by `basicHttpBinding` in my Web.config. Calling the WDSL file over HTTPS still worked, but on the other hand, it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are some limitations to the WSDL elements supported by the ABAP web service client functionality. There are notes that document what is and isn't supported:

- [944029](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/944029) - XML schema supported by ABAP proxy generation
- [1327511](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1327511) - Limitations and common problems in ABAP WSDL processing

You have two solutions in such cases:

1. If possible, get the web service publisher to modify their service to remove any elements that aren't supported. In most cases, this won't be possible.
2. Modify the WSDL to remove any unsupported elements. Unfortunately this can be quite tricky and will need to be done every time the WSDL changes (working from a diff made after the first change *may* be possible but will probably be more trouble than it's worth).